# Add html with css to div without editing main css

Tags: php, html, css

I have a message in my solution.
The problem is when I want to add a mail (html + css), the main css is changing.

This is a test concluded:

[image]

And this is an bad example (other mail):

[image]

I am putting an e-mail html like this:

```
<div class="inbox-view">
<?php
    function isHTML($string) {
        if ($string != strip_tags($string)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (isHTML($mail[0]->BODY)) {
        echo $mail[0]->BODY;
    } else {
        echo str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $mail[0]->BODY);
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You use the same classes with the main css?

Comment: the problem is i can't know the css and class of the mail

Comment: probably because you are echoing `$mail[0]->BODY` ......

Comment: No $mail[0]->BODY give me the html and css of mail to put it in the div (inbox-view)

Comment: how about iframe ?

Comment: Since the email body can contain anything (even broken HTML), you should definitely put it in an iframe to make sure it doesn't mess with the html/css on your page.

Comment: how  Magnus Eriksson?

Comment: How to put it in an iframe? `<iframe><?= $mail[0]->BODY ?></iframe>`

Comment: _Tip:_ You don't need to do this `str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $mail[0]->BODY);` manually. There is a PHP command that does the same: `nl2br($mail[0]->BODY);`

Comment: 1/ <iframe><?= $mail[0]->BODY ?></iframe> it's doesn't work it give me a empty iframe

Comment: 2/ Thx for nl2br function ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider using shadow DOM here as it will separate the css from other code on the page so that different parts do not clash. But i am afraid that you can do it using javscript only.
You can find the details on how to create shadow DOM from here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Answer (score 0):

How about using more specific selectors.

```
e.g. div#first p#myParagraph span.bolder
```

Or use **!important** as last resort.